# Programmatically set default column values based on folder in SharePoint Online

Tags: default-value, sharepoint-online, column-defaults

I'm working on enhancing metadata in our SharePoint online (O365) environment.  Since a portion of my user base is used to foldering (explorer style), I've started using default column values to automatically set values on any files added to that specific folder (we have content organized categorically by folder currently).  An example is our HR documents library - we have separate folders for recruiting, payroll, personnel files, etc. that automatically categorize files added to that folder with the same categories (recruiting, payroll, personnel, etc.).  This supports both "search" and "click" users and makes adoption WAY easier while getting important metadata.

I want to implement this in a larger, more dynamic fashion, so manually setting default column values on each folder is not going to be scalable.

How can I reference the top level folder within the library (or even the current folder) for each newly added file and populate the "category" field for that new file with that folder name?  I can do some very basic C# or Java code copy/paste, but bonus points for non-coding solutions =)

Comment: You may find this question gets more help at sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll try there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to use MS Flow to accomplish this in a pretty simple and straightforward fashion without managing custom views per team.  The concept at a high level was:

1. (Trigger) When a new document is created in a folder in the library
2. Get the link of the parent folder of the newly added document
3. Create a variable (or just code it out in the Flow step) to parse out the name of the parent folder from the parent folder link (should be all text to the right of the last "/")
4. Set the category field as the variable

I'm sure that you could do the same right in a SharePoint designer workflow, but I prefer flow due to the visual aspect of it and being far easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved through no coding.You can use the workflow to implement this by SharePoint Designer.

1. Create different view for different function team, and then use the view filter to show the document.
2. If you upload a file, use the workflow to set the metadata of the file. There are some known limitations: if you upload multiple files at the same time, the metadata for the file maybe does not work well;  or if you upload a folder, the meta will not work for it and the file in the folder may not be set to right metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that defeats the original requirement of using EITHER folders OR metadata.  I'll look a little more into other designer workflow options though.

Comment: This won't defeat the folders/metadata. you can still use both of them. But the actual work will be done by the workflow.